# Removing string/data in between special character

Tags: r

I have data:

> abc .,.. :*  # **jjfj kklkdld lldldl** # lflllf ll:''''
>
> nnbnmmm..? lkk # **iijij ... ookk** # ooogokog

These are multiple lines.

I want to delete data in between '#' and '#'

How to do it in R?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of regular expressions as implemented in for instance `sub`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in R with `sub`, `gsub` and similar functions. See and read `?sub` and `?regex` for more information. Below are two examples.

Example 1:

```
my.string <- "irrelevant # extract this # text"
gsub("^.*#(.+)#.*$", "\\1", my.string)
#[1] " extract this "
```

Example 2:

```
my.other.string <- "some # delete this # text"
sub("#.+#", "", my.other.string)
#[1] "some  text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use strsplit:

```
ll = unlist(strsplit("relevant # extract this # text",'#'))

ll[2]
#[1] " extract this "

paste0(ll[1], ll[3])
#[1] "relevant  text"
```